# conditionally populating anonymous type member in linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having a problem with the following LINQ query.  When the nested query (item.Items) has no objects I'm getting the exception "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source.".

How can I get the inner query to return an empty list to items within the query?

```
var items = from item in _repository.GetStreamItems()
                        select new
                            {
                                Title = item.Title,
                                Description = item.Description,
                                MetaData = item.MetaData,
                                ItemType = item.ItemType,
                                Items = from subItem in item.Items
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            Title = subItem.Title,
                                            Description = subItem.Description,
                                            MetaData = subItem.MetaData,
                                            ItemType = subItem.ItemType
                                        }
                            };
```

Here's the same query written using method calls instead of query syntax.  Same issue:

```
var items = _repository.GetStreamItems()
                .Select(x => new { Title = x.Title, Description = x.Description, MetaData = x.MetaData, ItemType = x.ItemType, 
                    Items = x.Items.Select(x2 => new { Title = x2.Title, Description = x2.Description, MetaData = x2.MetaData, ItemType = x2.ItemType, 
                        Items = x2.Items.Select(x3 => new { Title = x3.Title, Description = x3.Description, MetaData = x3.MetaData, ItemType = x3.ItemType }) }) });
```

Any ideas how to test for or avoid the null item.Items value?  I have a feeling it's something simple I'm missing.

Comment: Can you paste the exception stack trace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming it's LINQ to Objects and single item class name is `Item`, go with this one:

```
var items = from item in _repository.GetStreamItems()
                        select new
                        {
                            Title = item.Title,
                            Description = item.Description,
                            MetaData = item.MetaData,
                            ItemType = item.ItemType,
                            Items = from subItem in (item.Items ?? Enumerable.Empty<Item>())
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Title = subItem.Title,
                                        Description = subItem.Description,
                                        MetaData = subItem.MetaData,
                                        ItemType = subItem.ItemType
                                    }
                        };
```

`??` is called [**null-coalescing operator**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) and returns the value on the right if the value on the left is `null`.
In your specific example, we provide an empty sequence instead of `null` so the code does not crash.

The problem is you can't apply queries to a `null` object, and it seems like `item.Items` can be `null` in your case. A better solution would be to ensure that `Items` property returns a zero sequence when empty, not `null`.

If you have no control over the `StreamItem` class but have to do similar queries in many places, it might pay off to create a “safe” extension method that would return “denullified” items:

```
public static IEnumerable<Item> SafeGetSubItems(this StreamItem parent)
{
    return parent.Items ?? Enumerable.Empty<Item>();
}
```

This would allow you to always write:

```
Items = from subItem in item.SafeGetSubItems()
        select new
        {
            // ...
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. That worked perfectly for me. I agree about avoiding letting the Items property return null but I don't control that code.

Comment: @joshb: If the code is repetitive, you might want to use the second approach (see the edit). But it really depends on your situation.